# Best continuously updated resource about python web "plumbing"

Tags: python, wsgi, flup

I'm a programmer in Python who works on web-applications. I know a fair bit about the application level. But not so much about the underlying "plumbing" which I find myself having to configure or debug.

I'm thinking of everything from using memcached to flup, fcgi, WSGI etc.

When looking for information about these, online, Google typically delivers older-documents (eg. tutorials from before 2007), fragments of problems that may or may not have been resolved etc.

Are there any good comprehensive and up-to-date resources to learn about how to put together a modern, high-performance server? One that explains both principles of the architecture and the actual packages?

Answer (score 1):

Buy this.  [http://www.amazon.com/Scalable-Internet-Architectures-Developers-Library/dp/067232699X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232699X)

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something with the comprehensiveness of a book ... but I guess I'm just worried that books go out of date so quickly

Comment: I see that's from 2006 .. do you think it's still relevant

Comment: @interstar: Things don't change *that* rapidly.  The book is outstanding and will give you a basis for understanding the essence of web site plumbing.  Details *do* change, but once you have the foundation, you can easily track changes in the details.

Answer (score 1):

- General info about highly efficient web architecture: http://highscalability.com/
- Interesting Python related articles: http://www.onlamp.com/python/
- Printed magazine: http://pythonmagazine.com/

Answer (score 0):

*Zope* is a still evolving framework, written in *Python* and is documented online. For a start, see [Zope Concepts and Architecture](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/source/ZopeArchitecture.html). Like other *Python* based web frameworks, the [source](http://www.zope.org/DevHome/Subversion/FrontPage) is your best reference.

Note that *Zope* is not easy to grasp, and is different from frameworks like *Django*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this terminology to limit search results to the past year:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2860/google_how_to_access_filter_by_date_dropdown_box/